# Reading html content with without escaping?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, html-entities

I am trying to read the html content using innerHTML. It seems to convert the '<' in the text content to `'&lt;' .`

I would rather not to. Is there anything in JS that would allow me to render as such

Comment: In HTML, "<" *must* be encoded as `&lt;`. `innerHTML` will give you *valid HTML*. If you're interested in reading the *textual content* of a node, you want `innerText` instead…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lodash supports an unescape() function](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/unescape/) that does this.

For example,

```js
// This reads < as &lt;
let html = document.querySelector('.el').innerHTML
// This converts the &lt; back into <
html = _.unescape(html)
```

More answers are available in this question: [Unescape HTML entities in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)